# How To Get Date Value From A JSON File in Angular6

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I have a json file called data.json in my assets folder

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "project_name": "X project",
    "project_date": "December 1, 2019 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+1",
    "project_status": "vip",
    "rating": "5 star"
  }
]
```

Here Is my Angular service called home.service.ts

```
projectList = '../../../assets/data.json';



getProject() {
    return this.httpService
      .get(this.projectList)
      .map(res => JSON.parse(res.text(), this.reviver));
  }

 reviver(key, value): any {
    if ('project_date' === key) {
      return new Date(value);
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Here is my component.ts file

```
 projects: string[];

 showProject() {
    this.homeservice.getProject().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.projects= data as string[]; 
        console.log(this.projects);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

And this is my html file

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projects">
 <h5>{{ project.project_date | date }}</h5>
</div>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
res.text is not a function in home.service.ts
```

If I try it without the `.map(res => JSON.parse(res.text(), this.reviver));`

I get this error:

```
Invalid argument 'December 1, 2019 at 9:03:01 AM GMT+1' for pipe 'DatePipe'
```

Does anyone have a solution to how I can display this on the web page as a date? Thanks.

Comment: There are two questions there. How to properlys send HTTP requests and get the JSON response? This is covered by the Angular HTTP guide. Please, read it. Don't try random things. https://angular.io/guide/http. Then the second question is: "how to parse a date in an exotic, English-only format". My answer to that would be: don't. Fix the file so that it contains dates in the standard, ISO-8601 format. This format is standard, unambiguous, easy to parse, and supported natively by the date pipe.

Comment: JSON returned from HTTP responses is parsed automatically, therefore you have to remove the parsing you are doing now.

Comment: Alright, the other thing is how do I display the date on the page using angular date pipes?

Answer (score 2):

Your date should look like the following (without `at`):

```
"December 1, 2019 9:03:01 AM GMT+1"
```

There is no need to parse the response of your http request since it is done natively by angular

```
getProject() {
    return this.httpService
      .get(this.projectList)

  }
```

To display the date using a [format](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#usage-example)

```
{{project.project_date | date:'h:mm a z'}}
```

Comment: Okay. So, how do I display the date on the page using angular date pipe.

Comment: Thanks very much. I just got the result I want. It now displays on the page. Cheers.